# Spring Cloud Config Client cannot locate properties if context path is configured

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I am using Config server with relational database running at *http://localhost:8888/admin/dispatch-service/dev/0.1.* The server is running under a context path '/admin.

A client application connected to the spring cloud config server is unable to fetch properties from /admin context path (as it looks for localhost:8888 path). However, if the config server is running at http://localhost:8888/dispatch-service/dev/0.1. (without context path), the client app works fine and properties are also available.

How client app can read the properties if config server contains context path ?
I will really appreciate if anyone can help here ?

**Screenshots**

[config-server bootstrap.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YAfG.png)

[client application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW9iX.png)

[client application console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jxVR.jpg)

Comment: can you add the logs? There should be log statements from config client about trying to go to config server and what was returned.